# How do I check when my 403(b) balance will be 100% vested in Transamerica?

Tags: online-banking, 403b, vesting

I have a 403(b) plan in Transamerica with a balance that hasn't 100% vested yet. How do I check how long it will take for my balance to be fully vested in a Transamerica 403(b) account?

Comment: Are you talking about matching funds? (funds you contribute do not "vest" - they are always yours). Do you still work for the company that added the matching funds? Typically you don't get vested into any more funds after you leave the company.

Comment: And the company sets the vesting schedule - have you asked them what that is?

Comment: @DStanley My apologies, I had a misunderstanding on my end. I've removed the section about rollover. I am asking about vesting specifically.

Comment: The company that matches the funds sets the vesting schedule - Transamerica _may_ know the schedule or they may not. I would check with the HR or Benefits department of your company, or look through the benefits manual if you got one.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your employer's  Human Resources department.  Ask about their 403(b)'s "vesting schedule."  From there you can figure out what dollars vest when based on when you started contributing to the program, etc.

The terms of such things are set by the employer as part of their benefits policy.  Companies whose HR departments are on their game will have this information in the Employee Handbook or Benefits Guide.

Answer (score 0):

The employer decides what vesting schedule they want to use, as long at it meets the minimum schedule defined by the law.

There are usually a few places to look:

- HR should have this information. You may have to go to your corporate website to find the right person/office. Many companies put this document right on the corporate intranet or some other document storage system they have. Some companies have places  where you can find the documents that explain all the various benefit programs and their related forms.
- It might be on the Transamerica website. If you dig around your account after you log in you should be able to find documents related to your specific corporate program.
- You might have this information. This is usually in the documents they give new employees. It also may be mentioned during open season. Even though those documents focus on the health insurance benefits some employees put updates related to all the corporate benefits into that annual package.

Note: the percentage vested generally doesn't change after your last day of work. Some employers allow an employee to return after a short gap and keep them on the original vesting schedule. The documents should also explain this part.